# Continuous function and non-zero measure set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $g:[0,1] \to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Let $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure in this interval. Suppose that it takes a constant value in $A \subset [0,1]$, and $m(A) \neq 0$. It is certain that $g$ is constant in a interval in $[0,1]$?

Comment: I'm no measure theorist, but wouldn't $g(x) = x-1/2 + |x-1/2|$ be a counterexample? Then $g$ is continuous, and $0$ on $[0,1/2]$, which has non-zero measure. I'm writing as a comment because I'm not sure if I am (or the question is) missing something.

Comment: That is not a counterexample.  $[0,1/2]$ is an interval on which $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Consider a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) $A \subset [0,1]$ (a compact nowhere-dense set with nonzero Lebesgue measure), and let $g(x) = \text{dist}(x,A)$.  Then $g(x)=0$ for $x \in A$, but there is no interval of positive length on which $g$ is constant.

Comment: amazing simple example!